# Visual Studio Change which state a card is set to in VSTS when a changeset is marked resolved

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Currently when marking an item resolved in Visual Studio during a check in, the ticket is sent directly to the Done column on The taskboard. I would like the state to be set to s Ready To Test state in the project, which is the only state the exists under the resolved column.

Is this something that can change?

[image: States for a task]

Comment: can you provide a screendump of what your swimlane or taskboard looks like? I believe this is nothing that can be set in the `States` tab. Can you also show the `Rules` tab (right to the `States` tab)? In my case I cannot even see the `Rules` tab.

Comment: Just saw this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav). Haven't read it in its entirety. Maybe you should check it out, this might be possible by setting up a rule for state transitions

Comment: @DanDan You cannot define rules that will initiate a transition. You can only use transitions as conditions for other actions.